# how do i display an objects attributes from a different table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies if my terminology is off here.

I have a model for Users. I have a model for Products. Users have many products and Products belong to Users.

I am trying to have a Users index page that shows all Users and their associated Products with links to the individual User pages. My SHOW page is operating as I expect but I don't know how to show the User's Products on the index view.

**SHOW (this works)**

*Controller*

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @product = @user.products
end
```

*View*

```
<%= @user.name %>
<% if @user.products.any? %>
Product
<%= render @product %>
<% end %>
```

*Product Partial (referenced above)*

```
Serial Number: <%= product.serial %>
```

**INDEX (this does not work)**

*Controller*

```
def index
 @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @product = @users.product #trying to show
end
```

*View*

I am at a loss here. Anything I've thought made sense doesn't work for me.

I would like to do something like

```
<%= user.product.serialnumber %>
```

or

```
<%= user.product.id %>
```

How do I show attributes of the User's Products in a view? Why does it work in a partial in my SHOW action/view but not in my INDEX action? Do I have to use a partial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your index action, `@users` is a collection of users whereas in your show `@user` is a single user object.

When you say, `@users.product`, you are calling product on collection object and not user object. So what you have to do is, iterate `@users` collection in your view and call product on the object

Something like

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%user.products.each do |product|%>
     <%= user.name%>
     <%= product.serialnumber%>
     <%= product.id%>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks! i have tried that and get an undefined method 'product' for User

Comment: Looks like you named your association `products` instead of `product`. Modified my answer

Comment: looks like Rails understood that, but being a noob, I don't know what this error means exactly "undefined method `serial' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Product:0x007fcf9aef3000>"

Comment: for what it's worth, class Product belongs_to :user and class User has_many :products

Comment: I see that you edited that loop and it's working! Very interesting. Never would have figured that out. Thank you!